# Honda fit hybrid GP5 gear box warning?

Tags: honda, transmission

I have 2014 Honda fit hybrid (GP5)  which has 45000km milleage. Recently car started gave gearbox warning. I have changed the dct oil after warning appeared but it didn't resolve the issue. After driving sometime warning appears but there's no change in gear changing or pulling power. Everything feels normal. Warning gives with d indicator flashing. After warning appears car cannot put to park gear. When car restart warning get removed. I want expert advice what except before go to repair it. Car is not running now.[image]![error message]

Comment: It may have been cheaper to have taken it to a dealer when the warning first appeared, it may well be very much more expensive now...

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have the same warning in my honda fit. The car is driving well, but this message make me feel uncomfortable. Can you help me?

Comment: @Viraj - Please make this an answer so we can close the loop! :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it turns out that control unit circuit for gear box having some dirt. Cleaning it resolved the issue.